# How to eject a USB device (no icon) from a mac to be used in VM

Tags: terminal, command, usb, device

I have a PIC microcontroller that needs to be used as a USB device. I have already succeeded communicating the PIC with my MAC so that is no the issue. 
I can even see the device "mounted" with the command "system_profiler SPUSBDataType" that lists all USB devices connected with the computer.
I need this device to be used in a Ubuntu Virtual Machine so I need to be able to "disconnect" this device from the host (mac os)  and open in the VM.
How can I "disconnect" a non-iconed usb device from mac so I can "connect" to my VM? Any commands?

THanks a lot...

Comment: I did. I was something very much simple and stupid. You just need to add the device at the list of devices in the VM settings and you're good to go. Sorry for this late reply, btw.

Comment: hi can you provide the details on how you made it work? if possible can you answer your own question and accept it here so that in future reference people can see how you were able to solve it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to unmount a device on OSX with the `umount` command:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/umount.8.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I unmount a device that is not listed? The problem is that this is a pic18f4550 connected to be usb and I need to remove it from mac to use in a linux virtual machine

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not listed". It sounded from your question like you could see it listed in profiler? If this device is in use by anything on the host operating system you will need to kill that service (ie, unmount USB drive, stop a service for GPS USB unit, etc). Once your device is not in use by anything on the host OS you should be able to claim it on your VM client.

Comment: Notes from `man unmount`:
     Due to the complex and interwoven nature of Mac OS X, umount may fail often.  It is recommended that diskutil(1) (as in, ``diskutil unmount /mnt'') be used instead.